# Is it possible to mock locations for release build type

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-location, android-lint

I'd like to mock locations in release build type of Android app. I've created a special flavour *"mockable"* manifest  in `app/src/mockable/AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
</manifest>
```

But it seems that Android lint blocks from using this permissions in release build type. For command:

```
 ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

I got output:

```
:app:lintVitalMockableRelease                 
/home/fr/app/src/mockable/AndroidManifest.xml:3: Error: Mock locations should only be requested in a debug-specific manifest file (typically src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml) [MockLocation]
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

   Explanation for issues of type "MockLocation":
   Using a mock location provider (by requiring the permission
   android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION) should only be done in debug
   builds. In Gradle projects, that means you should only request this
   permission in a debug source set specific manifest file.

   To fix this, create a new manifest file in the debug folder and move the
   <uses-permission> element there. A typical path to a debug manifest
   override file in a Gradle project is src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml.

1 errors, 0 warnings
```

**Is it possible to generate release app with location mocking permission?**

Comment: Disable lint check for that flavor?

Comment: @WarrenFaith How to disable lint for only "mockable" flavour?

Answer (score 7):

Disable the MockLocation lint check for that particular permission, i.e.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"
        tools:ignore="MockLocation" />  
</manifest>
```

(Refer to http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks)

Answer (score 4):

The only solution I know for sure is to let lint report errors but don't let that abort the build process:

To enable that just add

```
lintOptions {
   abortOnError false
}
```

inside the `android` block.

You will still get lint errors and warnings but the build will continue.

I am not sure if you can put that inside the flavor definition or use a custom buildType for that. I have no project where I could test that.

Answer (score 0):

This is a caution. If you want a user to "mock location" then the user must enable mock locations in Android.

A production release is definitely possible, I have done this. You need to prompt the user to allow for "Mock Locations" like a developer/debug would.

Comment: Does this mean that this permission works the same as Settings->Developer options->Allow mock locations"?